# Kim says Saul could be a rat -- is that consistent with her character?

Tags: character, better-call-saul

In Season 6, E3, Kim and Jimmy are discussing Lalo's death and she suggests that Jimmy could choose to be a rat -- at that point she sounds very much like a criminal rather than a law-abiding citizen. Of course, she does do some questionable things but would she really take the cartel's side in anything? I don't think she would -- she is no murderer even if Jimmy does seem to be willing to be involved with murder indirectly and murderers (like Lalo and Walt and Jesse) directly.

Am I misinterpreting her statement or is she indeed disdainful of behavior that would make Saul "a rat?"

Answer (score 2):

There are several things at play here:

- First and foremost, being "a rat" in the eyes of a cartel is dangerous, and will put Jimmy's and her life in significant jeopardy. I think by using those words Kim simply emphasizes this aspect of that choice.
- Kim has grown to admire Jimmy's conning and cunning ways, and his ability to squeeze out of tough situations. Jimmy admitting to knowing De Guzman's true identity would possibly (subconsciously) undermine her respect for him, independent of the scenario.
- I think Kim didn't like to be the one to be told about Jimmy's relationship with one of the Salamanca's, because it puts her in a position where she has to (literally) act against her better judgment that Jimmy actually might have known the true identity of Lalo Salamanca.
- Kim doesn't like Suzanne Ericsen because of her past attitude towards Jimmy as the "scumbag disbarred lawyer".

Ultimately, this isn't Kim taking the cartel's side, nudging Jimmy into the direction of criminality or away from justice, but this is Kim believing in Jimmy's capabilities and embracing her love for living on the edge.

Comment: By this point, Lalo Salamanca has already visited Kim and Jimmy’s home. Jimmy is essentially already in it with the cartel. Kim doesn’t necessarily approve, but throughout the series, she’s made it clear that despite their love and partnership, both of them should be free to make their own choices. As such, she’s just outlining the situation Jimmy finds himself in: if he informs on Lalo, the cartel will certainly consider him a rat if they find out, with all the attendant danger.